# Android google play services lib

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having trouble with google play services lib.  I am following the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

My trouble is after importing the google play services lib I right click the application I am working on, go to properties, click on android and there is no google play services lib to select.  How are you suppose to make eclipse recognize the imported android project (which in my case is google-play-services_lib) as a library?  I am unsure of what I did wrong here.  Thanks for the comments and help!

Comment: check if google play services properties is checked as isLibrary. if not check it then it will show in properties under library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the google play services lib, click properties, click Android, and make sure the box next to "Is Library" is checked.

If that is checked, then remove the google play services lib, and then re-import, and make sure to check the box "copy into workspace". And then repeat the above steps.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  This one worked for me.  I have a few more questions:  Where do I get the following information?   /* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE"; and     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();  I am looking at the two ID's, but I do not know where they are coming from or how to obtain them.

Comment: Technically you don't need to worry about the .addTestDevice. As for the AD Unit ID you need to go to www.google.com/ads/admob/ to sign up and follow the instructions there to obtain your AD Unit Id. The reason you need this is so when the ad is viewed or clicked on, it knows whos ad it is and who to pay.

Comment: I would like to see how the ads look before publishing the app though, would I need the .addTestDevice for that? Also is admob free?

Comment: Yes, admob is free. And even without the .addTextDevice ads will show up.

Comment: Do I need to publish the app on google play before putting ads in with admob?  I wanted to test the app with ads in it before placing on google play but I am not sure if that is possible.  will the ads show up in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

First you ensure that you donwload it from the SDK Manager correctly. If yes then go to the folder **"\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib**

Then Import it into your current app workspace from **File >> Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace. Then goto your project properties, click on android,and add your Google play services then click ok.**

If you want more info see this page http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/